# How to stay on a page after validating PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a problem... I created a redirect loop, but I don´t know how to fix it or do it in another way. I have a registration.php with a form in it which send post-data to the validation.php, for validation and sending the data into a database. So far, so good. But if there is invalid data from the from, i can´t stay on the registration.php and show an error message.

So I saw a tutorial where the guy used something like this in his registration.php. If something went wrong inside the validation, he redirect to the same page where the data come from, in this case it would be from my validation.php back to my registration.php

`header("Location: registration.php?error=".$err_msg);
        exit();`

to take the value of the $err_msg and show it on the registration.php, he took the value in the registration.php out of the $_GET['error'] . If I am doing it like this, I'm getting a redirect loop. How is he doing that without the loop. Here's my form in the registration.php.

```html
registration.php

<?php 
     if(!empty($_GET['error'])){
        $err_msg= $_GET['error'];
         echo '<p class="error_msg">'.$err_msg. '</p>';  
       }
?>

<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="validation.php">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-14">
                                    <label for="inputState">Geschlecht *</label>
                                    <select id="inputState" name="gender" class="form-control" required="required">
                                        <option selected>Bitte Wählen...</option>
                                        <option value="frau">Frau</option>
                                        <option value="herr">Herr</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Vorname *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nachname *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Firma *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Straße *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="street" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>HausNr *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="hnr" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Postleitzahl *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="plz" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Ort *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email *</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Passwort *</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="required">
                                </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Registrieren" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

So if I do it like the guy from the tutorial in the validation.php  for example:

```php
 // Here database connection blah blah 

$err_msg = "";
if (!isset($_POST["gender"],
            $_POST["firstname"],
            $_POST["lastname"],
            $_POST["company"],
            $_POST["street"],
            $_POST["hnr"],
            $_POST["plz"],
            $_POST["city"],
            $_POST["email"],
            $_POST["password"])) {
    $err_msg = "Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus!";
}

if ($_POST['gender'] !== "herr" || $_POST['gender'] !== "frau") { //Validierung-
    $err_msg = "Bitte wählen Sie eine Ansprache!";
}
else{
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $err_msg = "Ungültige Emailadresse!";
        }
        else{
            if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $_POST['firstname']) == 0) {
                $err_msg = "Ungültiger Vorname!"; 
            }
            else{
                if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $_POST['lastname']) == 0) {
                    $err_msg = "Ungültiger Nachname!";
                }
                else{
                    if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['company']) == 0) {
                        $err_msg = "Ungültiger Firmenname!";  
                    }
                    else{
                        if (preg_match('/[\D][\-]?/', $_POST['street']) == 0) {
                            $err_msg = "Ungültige Straße!";   
                        }
                          else{
                                if (preg_match('/[0-9]{1-3}/', $_POST['hnr']) == 
                                    0) {
                                    $err_msg = "Ungültige Straße!";
                                }
                                else{
                                    if (preg_match('/[0-9]{5}/', $_POST['plz']) 
                                         == 0) {
                                        $err_msg = "Ungültige Postleitzahl!"; 
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (preg_match('/{10}/', $_POST['city']) 
                                            == 0) {
                                            $err_msg = "Ungültige Stadt!";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if (preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.* 
                                               [A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/', 
                                               $_POST['password']) == 0) {
                                                $err_msg = "Passwörter müssen:
                                                Einen Großbuchstaben enthalten
                                                Einen Kleinbuchstaben enthalten
                                                Eine Zahl enthalten
                                                Ein Sonderzeichen enthalten
                                                Und mindestens 8 Zeichen lang 
                                                sein!";

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if($err_msg !== ""){
    header("Location: registration.php?error=".$err_msg);
    exit();
}
else{
    database stuff and 
    header("Location: account.php);
    exit();
}
```

I'm right now in the redirect loop and getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in chrome. What is my mistake, how is he doing that without running into the loop?

I just want to go back to the registration.php to show an err_msg.

Or is there a way to validate the form data in the registration.php and send them after validation to the validation.php to insert the data into the database. I dont want to insert them from the registratio.php

Comment: You can use jquery validation if needs client side validation

Answer (score 0):

just add below code in registration.php:

```php
       <?php
          session_start();
          if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ echo $_SESSION['message']; 
          unset($_SESSION['message']);} 
       ?>
```

In your validation.php file add the code:

```php
       if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_SESSION['message']= "Ungültige Emailadresse!";
            header("Location: registration.php");
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: just checkout i have added new validation.php file code just replace whole code with this and try! Don't forget to put session variables in registration.php file which i added in first answer

Comment: I got it.. It has to be header("Location: ../registration.php"); dot dot slash before the file name!!!!!

Comment: That sounds good. Your registration file must be out of folder ../  means one directory back

Answer (score 0):

Update your validation.php file with this code:

```
    $err_msg = "";
    if (!isset($_POST["gender"],
                $_POST["firstname"],
                $_POST["lastname"],
                $_POST["company"],
                $_POST["street"],
                $_POST["hnr"],
                $_POST["plz"],
                $_POST["city"],
                $_POST["email"],
                $_POST["password"])) {
        $err_msg = "Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus!";
    }

    if ($_POST['gender'] !== "herr" || $_POST['gender'] !== "frau") { //Validierung-
        $err_msg = "Bitte wählen Sie eine Ansprache!";
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $err_msg = "Ungültige Emailadresse!";
            }
            elseif (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $_POST['firstname']) == 0) {
                    $err_msg = "Ungültiger Vorname!"; 
                }
                elseif (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $_POST['lastname']) == 0) {
                        $err_msg = "Ungültiger Nachname!";
                    }
                    elseif (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['company']) == 0) {
                            $err_msg = "Ungültiger Firmenname!";  
                        }
                        elseif (preg_match('/[\D][\-]?/', $_POST['street']) == 0) {
                                $err_msg = "Ungültige Straße!";   
                            }
                              elseif (preg_match('/[0-9]{1-3}/', $_POST['hnr']) == 
                                        0) {
                                        $err_msg = "Ungültige Straße!";
                                    }
                                    elseif (preg_match('/[0-9]{5}/', $_POST['plz']) 
                                             == 0) {
                                            $err_msg = "Ungültige Postleitzahl!"; 
                                        }
                                        elseif (preg_match('/{10}/', $_POST['city']) 
                                                == 0) {
                                                $err_msg = "Ungültige Stadt!";
                                            }
                                            elseif (preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.* 
                                                   [A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/', 
                                                   $_POST['password']) == 0) {
                                                    $err_msg = "Passwörter müssen:
                                                    Einen Großbuchstaben enthalten
                                                    Einen Kleinbuchstaben enthalten
                                                    Eine Zahl enthalten
                                                    Ein Sonderzeichen enthalten
                                                    Und mindestens 8 Zeichen lang 
                                                    sein!";

                                                }


    if($err_msg !== ""){
        $_SESSION['message']= $err_msg;
        header("Location: registration.php");

    }
    else{

        header("Location: account.php");

    }
```